# Multiple object selection with jQuery

Tags: jquery, class, click, slidedown

Basically I attempt to have a link slide down a div. This is fairly simple however I require multiple links sliding down their respective divs. I understand I can just name the links and divs unique classes and solve the problem that way, however this naturally also requires a duplication of the jQuery code for each link-div and i have a lot. I therefore need a general script. A simplified version of my situation is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a id=link1>toggle text 1</a>
    <div class=link1>TEXT 1</div>

    <a id=link2>toggle text 2</a>
    <div class=link2>TEXT 2</div>
</div>
```

My attempt at a jQuery general script for this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=link]').bind('click', function() {
        var $div = $(this).attr('id');
        if($('[class=' + div + ']').is(':visible')) {
            $('[class=' + div + ']').slideUp();
        } else {
            $('[class=' + div + ']').slideDown();
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

But as one might expect since I'm writing here it does not work. I am thinking is has to do with the ^= but I can't figure out how to improve it.

Comment: `if($('[class=' + div + ']').is(':visible')) {` should be `if($('[class=' + $div + ']').is(':visible')) {`, you've forgot the `$` in the variable name

Comment: Shoudn't your `div` variables be `$div` in the context of their use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't that work?

```
$("a").click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Haha wow I guess I still have to learn about all the preprogrammed functions in jQuery :P yes that works perfectly! Thanx a million!

Comment: Well, this code will bind to **all** `<a>` links in the page and slideToggle **any** next element. Not very safe/specific.

Comment: Sure! I didn't want to be specific without knowing his page, but I didn't like this '[id^=link]' selector. That was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- you were declaring a variable `$div` but using `div`
- to select by class, use `.classname` and not `'[class=...]`

Optimizations:

- select your div and re-use the variable `$div`to avoid re-selecting 3 times the same element
- in an event handler, `this` is the DOM element. To get its ID, just use `this.id`, not need for jquery

Here's the code:

```
$('[id^=link]').bind('click', function() {
    var id = this.id,
        $div = $('.' + id);

    if ($div.is(':visible')) {
        $div.slideUp();
    } else {
        $div.slideDown();
    }

    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/GSAfr/)**

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest having a common class on all your links, for example...

```
<a id="link" class="link">
```

and you can select multiple with...

```
$(".link")
```

alternative, you could select all A tags....

```
$("a")
```

Answer (score 0):

I realise that others are suggesting alternatives, and I would encorage you to look at them. To answer your specific problem I believe it lies with the variable names:

The lines of code with `div` in then, e.g.

```
if($('[class=' + div + ']').is(':visible')) {
```

Should possibly have `$div` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this more verbose example... hope this helps:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery Test Slider</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[id^=link]').bind('click', function () {
            var myDiv = $(this).attr('id');
            var isVis = $('[class=' + myDiv + ']').is(':visible');
            if (isVis) 
            {
                $('[class=' + myDiv + ']').slideUp();
            }
            else 
            {
                $('[class=' + myDiv + ']').slideDown();
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
<a id="link1">toggle text 1</a>
<div class="link1">TEXT 1</div>

<a id="link2">toggle text 2</a>
<div class="link2">TEXT 2</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```